# Squirrel sql client session timeout 

Tags: session, timeout, squirrel-sql

It is not related to whatever version it is, just working to find out how to change (of course increase) session timeout value of Squirrel Sql Client. Because I really get bored of getting kind of exception "Last packet sent to the server was .. ago"

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solution for MySQL:

- Right-click a connection alias and select "Modify alias"
- Click "Properties" and select the "Driver properties" tab
- Set the property "autoReconnect" to "TRUE"

Comment: When I go to the Driver properties tab of my Alias's properties, I see one entry for remarksReporting. Do I need to somehow add an entry for autoReconnect? How?

Comment: I explain the answer in terms of MySQL connection. I mean, I am not sure whether you are using mysql or not and also not sure the reason for your case is because of this difference or not.

Comment: I'm using Oracle, not sure if that is the difference.

Comment: Instead or reconnecting you might want to keep the connection alive, there is an option to do that in the same window, see my answer below.

Comment: @user454322 Thanks. However, I suppose the configurations such as connection timeout vs that be done in the sql server side should not let your connection keep itself alive.

Comment: I think that if the 'Sleep for' parameter is smaller than the timeout configured in the sql server your connection will keep alive.

Comment: Yes, maybe, although it depends on the server configuration, still your idea worth trying. Thanks again.

Answer (score 22):

You can keep the connection alive by doing the following:

On *Aliases->Modify the Selected Alias (pencil icon)-> Properties-> Connection (tab)*

Check *Enable Keep-Alive*

and enter a simple query, in PostgreSQL I use `SELECT 1;`, in Oracle should be something like `SELECT 1 FROM dual`

Comment: At least for Oracle, [do **not** use a trailing semicolon `;`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40179795/1529709)!

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem with my local development machine. Since using the driver property "autoReconnect" is discouraged by SQuirreL, I looked for another alternative which **fixes the root cause**.

[image: Feature is discouraged.]

I have access to the `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` directory on my Linux VM, so I could tweak the variable `wait_timeout`. Previously, it was set to `600` (600 / 60 seconds per minute = 10 minutes). I then set it to `28800` which is the [MariaDB default](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/server-system-variables/#wait_timeout).

After restarting the MySQL server using `service mysql restart`, everything worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

If you're connecting to an Apache Derby db, use the following keep-alive test SQL:

```
VALUES 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Locate the the `prefs.xml` in the installation directory and change the default `loginTimeout` value to your desired value and you are done.