# Squirrel SQL Resonnect Session

Tags: squirrel-sql

In my Squirrel SQL, I've got a few session tabs, each with a number of open tabs for queries I have run in the past and corresponding query results.

That is very handy should I want to "re-live the experience of firing a query" or quickly modify a query if I need to tweak that.

Sadly, after a period of inactivity (I have learnt [how to increase session timeout of Squirrel SQL Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219864/squirrel-sql-client-session-timeout), so that is not part of the question), I no longer can fire any queries in that tab, as shown in the picture below

[image: Timed out session on Squirel SQL]

Is there a way to re-connect expired session to a DB connection again or any other way to fire the queries, other than copy and paste them from the expired session tab to a newly connected session?

Answer (score 7):

You can reconnect the session using *Session* →  *Reconnect* or `Ctrl-Alt-T`.

Comment: Yes, but that is not the option as I mentioned as that would create new tab, whereas I would like to connect new session to an existing tab so all my queries etc. are kept.

Comment: Hello, I'm using SQuirreL version 3.8.1. 

When I press Ctrl+Alt+T I get the following question: 
Close the current connection to the database and open a new one? 
If I choose Yes, the SQuirreL reconnect to the current database without opening a new tab and I'm able to re-run the current query. In the console I see: Reconnected to XXXXXXX

Comment: I did not have a chance to check - I don't work with SS on daily basis

Comment: `Ctrl-Alt-T` works as @ecg says on version 4.2.0 (and probably earlier versions): The connection is reestablished in the current tab.